# Parse JSON object created by a PDO statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, pdo

Here is my problem

I looked through Stak overflow and other websites but can't find an answer that solves my actual problem...

I call a php file from an AJAX request, my php file gets data from my db.

I'm making a pdo statement to get data from my db :

```
//initialize vars such as $db ...
$get = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable_id=1");
$get->execute();
echo json_encode($get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

//COLUMNS IN MY TABLE ARE ID, NAME, PHONE, INFO
```

so that object is returned to my ajax query
BUT I don't know how to fetch this object into my ajax/jquery statement to use its data...

Response from console :

```
[Object{id="1",name="myname",phone="8888888",info="information"}]
```

code...

```
success : function(response){
    var id = '';
    var name = '';
    var phone = '';
    var info = '';
}
```

please tell me how to parse, i tried json.parse(response), but can't display any data from this...

thanx

Comment: Show an example of the output

Comment: try `console.log(response)` and update your question with what the console reports is coming back. also update your question with the entire AJAX call. If you're sending JSON data back, you should use a `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX call.

Comment: response from console : [Object{id="1",name="myname",phone="8888888",info="information"}]

Comment: So you should just use `response.id` as the id and so on? You've obviously done everything else right.

Comment: it does not work... if i make something like "alert(response.id)" i have an empty alert back....

Comment: wth... i have to do this : "alert(response[0].id);" to get my data... looks like my fetch_assoc gives me a multidimensionnal array...

Comment: @Julo0sS Using `fetchAll` will return an array of all of the responses. If you know you're just getting 1 response back, try using `fetch` instead (if you don't want the outer array)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
success : function(response){
  var data = JSON.parse(response);
  var id = data.id;
  var name = data.name;
  var phone = data.phone;
  var info = data.info;
}
```

That should do the trick.